# Evidences proving or refuting the role of Russian KGB in creation of the modern day leftist ideology?

Tags: ideology, soviet-union, cold-war

There are people who believe that much of modern leftism boils down to anti-western sentiment.

For example, ex-KGB agent *Yurl Bezmenov* [has gone on record](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3qkf3bajd4) (video, YouTube, 1h 20m) stating that the majority of the KGB's activities were centered around spreading anti-western ideology in the United States.
He stated that the goal was to demoralize at least one generation of American youths to go against their self-interests and the interests of the country. According to *Bezmenov*, the Cold War perhaps not coincidentally was happening at the same time as the Western counterculture movement, which has evolved into modern day leftism.

This kind of theory is often dismissed as paranoia; however, *Bezmenov* clearly states their goals and methods and how successful the program was.

**Is there any credible evidence that proves or refutes *Bezmenov's* statements** about the KGB's role in creating/supporting the leftist movement primarily with the goal of demoralizing the Western society?

Comment: Why would a communist consider communism to be going "against their self-interests and the interests of the country"

Comment: @SamIam - to asnwer your direct question, because that's pretty much what is taught (including in USSR). "Self interests" are bad. "Internationalism" is good. The latter was far more obvious in the early days, say up till late 1930s. To answer indirectly, because most Americans prior to 1960s considered communism to be against the interest of their country (and only changed that after mass brainwashing by left-leaning educators and mass media).

Comment: @SamIam From what Bezmenov says I gather that the KGB were not trying to spread communism for idealistic reasons, but rather using it opportunistically as a weapon to subvert culture, waging asymmetric warfare against the west.

Comment: Video of the KGB officer:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3qkf3bajd4

Comment: This question was closed as opinion-based. I 've just edited it to make it more objective, and casted my vote to reopen

Answer (score 3):

> Much of modern leftism boils down to anti-western sentiment

You say that, but never explain any aspects of American leftism that can actually be construed as anti-western sentiment.

> The Cold War perhaps not coincidentally was happening at the same time as the Western counterculture movement

Implying that this is a direct result of Soviet mind-control as opposed to maybe the war in Vietnam or [any number of other things that were going on at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterculture_of_the_1960s) is a bit historically ignorant.

> This kind of theory is often dismissed as paranoia

Yeah, it's kinda reminiscent of [McCarthy's](http://history.howstuffworks.com/historical-figures/mccarthyism.htm) spiel around that time.

EDIT
I was requested to give an example of a "leftist" objective that doesn't undermine "Western values". Both conceptualizations in quotes are 200% subjective, but I'd say the creation of National Parks fit the bill. I think it would definitely be a reach to say that conservation efforts subvert Western ideology, and Roosevelt sort of kicked off progressiveness in mainstream US politics.

Comment: An answer telling the OP that their evidence isn't good enough isn't that helpful.  There's a reason why we close bad questions, and there's a reason why you can't answer a question once it's been closed.

Comment: 1) I challenge you to find an example of a leftist mission that does not undermine some aspect of the west whether it is subversion of a particular traditional western value or belief or the left's preference for non-westerners over westerners.

Comment: I am mostly suggesting the theory and what people think of it.

Most of my evidence is from this KGB officer's account. He describes exactly the mission in subverting the west. McCarthy's methods may have been wrong, but I believe based on this officer's account his concerns were based in reality.

Comment: Video of officer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3qkf3bajd4

Comment: I edited my answer.